# IONIC + Vue.js not working getters in VUEX

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, vuex, state-management

Hello developers I'm working with Ionic and Vue+Vuex in this app, but eventually, I can't access my state from my getters for some reason.

As usually the management state is settled for that purpose with actions getters, mutations, and state.

```
import { createStore } from "vuex";

const urlLogin = "http://localhost:3006/auth";
const urlUser = "http://localhost:3006/user";

const store = createStore({
  state() {
    return {
      userRegisteredState: false,
      allUsersState: [],
    };
  },

  mutations: {
    commit_get_all_users(state, payload) {
      console.log(payload);
      return (state.allUsersState = payload);
    },
  },

  getters: {
    getterGetAllUsers(state) {
      console.log(state);//checking all state (See image )
      console.log(state.allUsersState)//checking only the item I want to consume from state (See image )
       return state.allUsersState;
    },
   
  },

  actions: {
     //=================================================================
     //============================================================
    async getAllUsers({ commit }) {
      fetch(`${urlUser}/get/all/users`, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://localhost:8100",
        },
      })
        .then((result) => {
          return result.json();
        })
        .then((result) => {
          console.log(result);
          commit("commit_get_all_users", result);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
          error;
        });
    },
  },
});

export default store;
```

[image]
then on my component , in this case that one referring to get all users I set this logic:

```
<template>
  ...some tags...
</template>
<script>

import { mapActions, mapGetters } from "vuex"; 

export default {
  name: "AllUsersComponent",
   data() {
    return {
      allUsers: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(["getAllUsers"]),

    getAllUsersFront() {
      this.$store.dispatch("getAllUsers");
    },
    ...some methods....

  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["getterGetAllUsers"]),

    getterGetAllUsersFunction() {
      console.log(this.$store.getters.getterGetAllUsers);
      return this.$store.getters.getterGetAllUsers;
    },
  },
  async mounted() {
    this.getAllUsersFront();
  },
  created() {
    this.getAllUsersFront();
    this.getterGetAllUsersFunction;
    console.log(this.getterGetAllUsersFunction);
  },
  watch: {},
};
</script>
<style>
</style>
```

On my main.js file store is imported according to IONC in this way

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import './gapi.js'
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store/index"; //importando vuex
import loginComponentTag from "./components/Login";
import allUsersComponentTag from "./components/all-users-component"
// import GoogleSignInButton from 'vue-google-signin-button-directive'

import { IonicVue } from "@ionic/vue";
/* Core CSS required for Ionic components to work properly */
import "@ionic/vue/css/core.css";

/* Basic CSS for apps built with Ionic */
import "@ionic/vue/css/normalize.css";
import "@ionic/vue/css/structure.css";
import "@ionic/vue/css/typography.css";

/* Optional CSS utils that can be commented out */
import "@ionic/vue/css/padding.css";
import "@ionic/vue/css/float-elements.css";
import "@ionic/vue/css/text-alignment.css";
import "@ionic/vue/css/text-transformation.css";
import "@ionic/vue/css/flex-utils.css";
import "@ionic/vue/css/display.css";

/* Theme variables */
import "./theme/variables.css";


const app = createApp(App)
  .use(IonicVue)
  .use(store) 
  .use(router)
  
app.component("LoginComponent", loginComponentTag);
app.component("AllUsersComponent",allUsersComponentTag)

router.isReady().then(() => {
  
  app.mount("#app");

});
```

And my vue.config.js is settled in this way:

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    proxy: "http://localhost:8100",
  },
};
```

I checked my logs and eventually.

Literally, the situation is that despite having my state populated with data, unless I retrieve the whole state, I can't retrieve a particular item from it, cause the response is nothing.
Is there any configuration I'm omitting in this process I need to have in mind?

Comment: for "failed to load components" You may have missed importing ionic components you have used in the template and add adding them to `components` object..

Comment: #Suraj this warnings on components guess don't have anything to do with  my attempts of retrieving data from my state through getters

Comment: i just could simply put in my template a div for test purpose  an still the problem persists

Comment: `this.getterGetAllUsersFunction` is not a function call... Also is your API `getAllUsers` working and getting you data?

Comment: is a computed function

Comment: where are you actually trying to use the getter in your code? the sample you provided is hard to follow

Comment: in one of my components in this case AllUsersComponents , which eventually  is inserted in one of the views