# Accessing a Proxy object in Vue3

Tags: proxy, vuejs3

how can I access a fetch response  throwing a Proxy Object in Vue.js.
Literally I trigger a method in my Vue.js  component that calls a computed function that connects a getter in my Vuex, on code would be like this :

```
METHOD IN COMPONENT

methods: {
    ...mapActions(["getAllUsers"]),


    async gettingAllusers() {
      const target = await this.getterGetAllUsers;
      console.log(target);
      return target;
    },
  },

COMPUTED IN COMPONENT

 computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["getterGetAllUsers"]),

    getterGetAllUsersFunction() {
      return this.$store.getters.getterGetAllUsers;
    },
  },

VUEX

const store = createStore({
  state() {
    return {
      userRegisteredState: true,
      allUsersState: {},
    };
  },

  mutations: {
    
   commit_get_all_users(state, payload) {
      state.allUsersState =  payload;
      console.log(state.allUsersState);
      return state.allUsersState;
    },
  },

  getters: {
    getterGetAllUsers(state) {
      console.log(state);
      console.log(state.allUsersState)
       return state;
    },
  },

  actions: {
   
    async getAllUsers({ commit }) {
      fetch(`${urlUser}/get/all/users`, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      })
        .then((result) => {
          return result.json();
        })
        .then(async (result) => {
          await commit("commit_get_all_users",{...result});
          console.log(result);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
          error;
        });
    },
  },
});

export default store;
```

Literally in my component a trigger a computed function that is called by a method on the same component , using as source data an action  that fetches and commit that data in the state in order to be retrieved by the getter so as to be used in the component
This I s my result but I can't access the data target :

[image]

Any help would be amazing

Comment: The proxy is not a problem because it doesn't change how you access the data.  You should describe the code problem you're having instead

Comment: What do you mean when you say "can't access the data target"?  What happens when you log it?

Comment: in the [[Target]] comes all data , but how can i access it?, i have tried to disaggregate  the proxy object  result of the getter but the data keeps the same as in the image , being imposible to access  it

Comment: Like this:  `console.log(state.allUsersState);`  What do you see?

Comment: an Empty Proxy, reason why have to bring the whole state object

Comment: thats the point that getter can not access a specific item in the state but the whole object: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66598599/ionic-vue-js-not-working-getters-in-vuex

Comment: is my issue  in fact though I'm asking in different manners in order to find a  solution

Comment: It's only because the async function isn't finished yet the first time the getter logs.  It will log a second time and be defined.  Why do you need to log the getter anyway?  If you use it in the template directly, you'll probably see the data (I do when using your code.)  I would suggest posting all your code to https://codesandbox.io to show why this is a problem

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should be able to access the proxy content using `console.log({ ...myProxy })` if you have nested proxies, you could also do a json stringify/parse

```js
const target = {
  message: "hello",
  nestedProxy: new Proxy({message:"nested"}, {}),
};

const proxy1 = new Proxy(target, {});

console.log(proxy1)
console.log({...proxy1})
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(proxy1)))
```

Comment: Is weird but disaggregating the proxy then i would recive for my first item a proxy to , i mean: { allUsersState: Proxy, userRegisteredState: true}

Comment: you could have a proxy nested in the other proxy, in which case you could loop and destructure those too, but a `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` will convert those as-well

Comment: Object.keys(myProxy) works as well, which feels a bit simpler to me.  It's frustrating they don't properly proxy the expected functions of primitives like Array to their inherent objects, hopefully they'll get around to that eventually.

Answer (score 5):

I know looks weird but, that works like a charm (even nested proxy).

```js
   const purchase = JSON.parse(
      JSON.stringify(store.state.cases.purchase_case)
    );
```