# Vue3 quick access printing Target in a "Proxy" object

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Vue3 prints everthing as an a "Proxy" object.

I know the value is inside [[Target]], but I don't want to keep expading Proxy->[[Target]] every single time.
Just wanted to let clear, this does't change the output at all. it is just a 'cleaner' way to see stuff.

An example:

```
const b = 'value'

console.log(value)

Output -> { Proxy: { [[Handler]]: ..., [[Target]]: 'value', [[IsRevoked]]: false }
```

Answer (score 9):

okay, this works.

```
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(b))).
```

for more info.
[Accessing a Proxy object in Vue3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66605274/accessing-a-proxy-object-in-vue3)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`toRaw`](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-advanced.html#toraw) function to "deproxy" your proxied objects.

```js
const  {reactive, toRaw} = Vue
const foo = reactive({bar: 'baz'})
const qux = toRaw(foo)
console.log(foo)
// Proxy(Object) {bar: 'baz'}
console.log(qux)
// {bar: 'baz'}
```

```html
<tt>Open your browser's console to see the difference.</tt>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
```